# How to run Jest tests on WebStorm and WSL

Tags: jestjs, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying run Run/Debug configuration on WebStorm. I have configuration:

[image]

And when I run that configuration I got:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/dtokarczyk/Develop/Company/e-home-react/\wsl$UbuntuhomedtokarczykDevelopCompanye-home-reactnode_modulesjestbinjest.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know how jest path I should add. Terminal tests work fine.

Answer (score 1):

using WSL2 UNC paths is not supported. Some related tickets (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43279, for example) are fixed in the next major update (2020.1), but general support is still not there. Please follow [IDEA-197573](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197573) and [WEB-39819](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39819) for updates